# Have series label displaying only once per series in eCharts

Tags: echarts

I'd like to show a label per series in my echarts chart, to make it a little easier to read than if I had a separate legend and color-coded the series. However it's not obvious to me how to achieve that - if I set series.label.show = true, then I get a label per data point:

[image: maybe a bit too busy?]

Is there a way to just have a single label, at the very right of these series? I have been tweaking around with the series-line.label but it is not obvious to me how to achieve this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to limit the number of labels with `formatter` (change divider in the `labelFilter`) and fix the overlap with `textBorderWidth`. See example below.

P.S. Also you can [fine-grained control the labels](https://gist.github.com/creadone/197b184f027d09d1d62997409cf9f23e) but it's not quite simple.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var sequence = () => Array(Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 5) + 5)).fill().map(() => Math.sqrt(Math.random() * 100));
var labelFilter = (obj) => obj.dataIndex % 3 === 0 ? obj.data : '';

var option = {
  tooltip: {},
  legend: {
    data: ['Label']
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
      name: 'Series1',
      stack: 'y',
      type: 'line',
      data: sequence(),
      step: true,
      color: 'green',
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: labelFilter,
        position: [10, 30],
        distance: -30,
        textBorderWidth: 2,
        textBorderColor: 'white',
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Series2',
      stack: 'y',
      type: 'line',
      data: sequence(),
      step: true,
      color: 'blue',
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: labelFilter,
        position: [10, -30],
        distance: 30,
        textBorderWidth: 3,
        textBorderColor: 'white',
      },
    },
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying to this - yes, that works great, thank you.