# How to limit number of points shown on scatter series?

Tags: javascript, performance, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, echarts

I'm ploting a big group of data points (about 2000 points) on a scatter plot, but many of them group at a small region of the graph and it damages the performance of the graph, starting to get slower and freezee. Is there a way to limit the number of data points rendered at a time?

I'm using Jupyter and javascript to plot with echart.

This is my code:

```
myChart.setOption({
            animation: false,
            backgroundColor: new echarts.graphic.RadialGradient(0.3, 0.3, 0.8, [{
                offset: 0,
                color: '#f7f8fa'
            }, {
                offset: 1,
                color: '#cdd0d5'
            }]),
            title: {
                text: 'Receita e Patrimonio de Clientes',
                left: 'center'
            },
            grid: {
                left: '3%',
                right: '4%',
                bottom: '3%',
                containLabel: true
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'value',
                name: 'ROA',
                nameLocation: 'center',
                nameTextStyle: {
                  lineHeight: 25
                },
                scale: true,
                axisLabel: {
                    formatter: '{value}%'
                },
                //min: 0,
                //max: 1.2
                
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value',
                name:'Patrimonio',
                nameLocation: 'center',
                scale: true,
                nameTextStyle: {
                  lineHeight: 130
                },
                axisLabel: {
                    formatter: 'R${value}'
                },
                //min:0,
                //max:600000
            },
            dataZoom: [
                {
                    type: 'slider',
                    show: true,
                    xAxisIndex: [0],
                    start: 0,
                    end: 35
                },
                {
                    type: 'slider',
                    show: true,
                    yAxisIndex: [0],
                    left: '93%',
                    start: 0,
                    end: 35000000
                },
                /*{
                    type: 'inside',
                    xAxisIndex: [0],
                    start: 1,
                    end: 35
                },
                {
                    type: 'inside',
                    yAxisIndex: [0],
                    start: 29,
                    end: 36
                }*/
            ],
            series: [{
                data: data_points,
                type: 'scatter',
                symbolSize: 20,
                emphasis: {
                    label: {
                        show: true,
                        formatter: function (param) {
                            return param.data[2];
                        },
                        position: 'top'
                    }
                },
                itemStyle: {
                    shadowBlur: 10,
                    shadowColor: 'rgba(120, 36, 50, 0.5)',
                    shadowOffsetY: 5,
                    color: new echarts.graphic.RadialGradient(0.4, 0.3, 1, [{
                        offset: 0,
                        color: 'rgb(251, 118, 123)'
                    }, {
                        offset: 1,
                        color: 'rgb(204, 46, 72)'
                    }])
                },
                markLine: {
                    lineStyle: {
                        type: 'solid'
                    },
                    data: [
                        {yAxis: 300000},
                        { xAxis: 0.6 }
                    ]
                },
                large: true,
                largeThreshold: 100
            }] // We just need to create this
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need something like a sampling. I haven't seen this on Echarts, but I solved this problem through data truncation: you just inserting each second, third or fourth datapoint from the you array. It based on exact division and data index.

Please take a look on this solution: [Have series label displaying only once per series in eCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069291/have-series-label-displaying-only-once-per-series-in-echarts/63078255?r=SearchResults#63078255)